# Discord.js ForEach function not working in V12

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I had a V11 code function to add a role if members were assigned a role from a integration, in this case give them a role when they get their automatic twitch sub role.

In V12 I cannot get it to work, thanks for the help in advance

PS: This is only ment for one server, hence why I dont clearify which guild.

V11 code:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    function autosub() {
        userss = client.guilds.get("358851471435104256").members;
        userss.forEach(element => {
            if ((element.roles.has("359382759434616832")) || (element.roles.has("463817515856822283")) || (element.roles.has("642181346197766165")) || (element.roles.has("526192023556980736")) || (element.roles.has("684173233754341552"))) {
                element.addRole("463821375061360640");
            } else {
                element.removeRole("463821375061360640");
            }
        }
        )
        setTimeout(autosub, 900000);
    }
    autosub();
});
```

New V12 code:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    function autosub() {

        client.guild.members.cache.forEach(element => {
            if ((element.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "359382759434616832")) || (element.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "463817515856822283")) || (element.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "642181346197766165")) || (element.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "526192023556980736")) || (element.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "684173233754341552"))) {
                element.addRole("463821375061360640");
            } else {
                element.removeRole("463821375061360640");
            }
        }
        )
        setTimeout(autosub, 900000);
    }
    autosub();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> client.guild.members.cache.forEach(...

Could it be because you called 'guild' instead of '[guilds](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds)' ?

[edit] By the way it seems to me that 'guilds' in v12 returns a GuildManager and not a [Collection as in v11](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds), so maybe there is additionnal unwrapping that should occurs before you get to use 'members'. That leads me to think that you should probably call '[cache](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache)' before 'members', isn't it?

[edit] ...and 'cache' returning a collection, you'll probably have use an appropiate 'get(...)' to obtain the Guild.

[discord.js](/questions/tagged/discord.js)